# Why Bamboo fails? Salesforce Continuous Integration

Tags: migration-tool, continuous-integration

I have a stash repository and Bamboo to build. I have created a task that runs the build.xml. But I when i run the plan (build plan) I get this error which doesnt say much :

Failing task since return code of [/usr/dev/fx/builds/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1//bin/ant -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/BERS-AMS-JOB1 -f build.xml deployEmptyCheckOnly -Dsfdc.username=mnimbal@cffc.com.dev......] was -1 while expected 0

What error is this?

Comment: Assuming deployEmptyCheckOnly is the name of the Ant target, what does that target do?

Comment: <target name="deployEmptyCheckOnly">
      <echo level="info">Testing the deploy</echo>
      <sf:deploy
          checkOnly="true"
          logType="Debugonly"
          username="${sfdc.username}"
          password="${sfdc.password}"
          serverurl="${sfdc.serverurl}"
          deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
          pollWaitMillis="${sfdc.pollWaitMillis}"
          maxPoll="${sfdc.maxPoll}" 
          runAllTests="true" />
    </target>

Comment: its just trying to runall tests. I dont think its to  do with target. it is something before that.

Comment: I assume Bamboo is reporting the exit code of Ant and Ant is returning that exit code because sf:deploy is return a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @ManjunathNimbal, it's a bit hard to tell what is going on but you will probably get better luck on the atlassian boards. That looks like a bamboo error rather than an error from the force.com migration tool.

Comment: Do you have the "The build will produce test results" option checked in your Task?

Comment: Can you post the huge chunk of the log before that line as well? When my builds fail in Bamboo, they return result code 1, but the deployment still happens.

Comment: @cricketlang  I will do that check. I will post the log. Thanks for helping me I am really great full, feel like i am hitting dead end

Comment: 16-Dec-2014 16:05:54  Failing task since return code of [/usr/dev/fx/builds/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1//bin/ant -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/BERS-AMS-JOB1 -f build/build.xml deployEmptyCheckOnly -Dsfdc.username=mnimbal@yyyy.com.dev -Dsfdc.password= -Dsfdc.serverurl=https://test.salesforce.com] was -1 while expected 0 
16-Dec-2014 16:05:54  Parsing test results under /scratch/bamboo-agent/fxsydapp02/xml-data/build-dir/BERS-AMS-JOB1... 
16-Dec-2014 16:05:54  Finished task 'Deploy to CRDRY' with result: Failed 
16-Dec-2014 16:05:54  Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'

Comment: Ant migration tool works perfectly fine on my laptop but its only problem with bamboo @keith C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. It was due to an ANT_HOME. Found an agent on bamboo where ANT_HOME was configured and made sure that only that agent runs for my plan. It worked fine.

It took me 100 attempts to see "green". At 100th run I was able to deploy.